# Interface menu, close if opened and user clicks outside menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to improve the interface of the menu here:

http://jsfiddle.net/u5brv/2/

I think it's great that it is toggled on click but I do think that if the user clicks anywhere else, for example, the bottom corner of the screen, the menu should toggle close if it isn't already.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#nav li').mousedown(function () {
        $('ul #items').toggle(100);
    });
});
```

How would one approach this in an efficient a way as possible? If the menu is open do we need to track every mouse click and see if it is on the menu or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to attach a click handler to the `document` which closes the menu:

```
$('#nav li').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('ul #items').toggle(100);
});

$(document).click(function() {
    $('#items').hide();
});
```

Note that `stopPropagation` is required on the opening link to stop the event reaching the document itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#nav li').mousedown(function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        $('ul #items').toggle(100);
    });
     $(document).mousedown(function(e) {
         $('ul #items').css('display','none'); //make all inactive`enter code here`
    });
});
```